# Get users by Department from Admin Directory API using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-admin-sdk

I have the following (mostly) working script using the Admin Directory API. However, rather than pulling the entire domain - I would like to just pull the information for a specific department.

```
function listAllUsers() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var pageToken, page, count = 0;
  var listArray = [];
  listArray.push(['full name', 'first name', 'last name', 'email', 'department', 'ID'])
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: 'example.co.uk',
      orderBy: 'givenName',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        listArray.push([user.name.fullName, user.name.givenName, user.name.familyName, user.primaryEmail, user.organizations, user.id,]);
      }
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
    break; // This means you only get one page
  } while (pageToken);
  try {
    var outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('allMembers');
    outputSheet.getDataRange();
  } catch(err) {
    var outputSheet = ss.insertSheet('allMembers', 2);
  }
  outputSheet.getDataRange().clear();
  outputSheet.getRange(1, 1, listArray.length, listArray[0].length).setValues(listArray);
  outputSheet.getRange(1, 6, outputSheet.getLastRow(), 4).setHorizontalAlignment("center");
  outputSheet.getRange(1, 1, outputSheet.getLastRow(), 1).setHorizontalAlignment("center");
  var width = [150, 150, 180, 250, 250, 200];
  formatSheet(outputSheet, width);
}
```

I have tried to filter to the domain by using user.organization[].domain but just got error messages. I changed the parameter `user.organizations` to `user.organizations[].department` as documented [in the Admin SDK reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource).

This initially threw out a SyntaxError, and when changed to `user.organizations[0].department` it threw out the error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined

I omitted the brackets altogether and used `user.organizations.department`, but got:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "department" from undefined

Also, if possible I would like to list the Department and Title separably. Currently, it exports the information in this format:

`{customType=work, name=, location=002, title=Technical Support Manager, department=Technical Support, primary=true}`

The current display:
[image: Here is a screenshot of how the information is displayed in a Google Sheet]

My desired output format:
[image: Here is a screenshot of how I would like it to appear]

Comment: If you tried to do it one way and get error messages, would it not make sense to share said code and said error messages? Have you tried a different query? Also, your department and title are already separate values, so I'm not sure what you are having difficulty with.

Comment: Have updated the post to show what I have tried and give some screenshots to explain things a little better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting those errors because some of the users in your domain don't have the department/ title user property.

Adding 2 variable and `try.. catch` blocks should allow the code to work as you expect.

Here is the updated code:

```
function listAllUsers() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var pageToken,
    page,
    count = 0;
    var listArray = [];
    listArray.push(['full name', 'first name', 'last name', 'email', 'department', 'title', 'ID'])
    do {
        page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
                domain : 'example.com',
                orderBy : 'givenName',
                pageToken : pageToken
            });
        var users = page.users;
        if (users) {
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                var user = users[i];
                var department,
                title; // Addded two new variables 
                try { // Try to get the users department if there is an error push the error to the array
                    department = user.organizations[0].department;
                } catch (e) {
                    department = e
                }
                try {// Try to get the users title if there is an error push the error to the array
                    title = user.organizations[0].title;
                } catch (e) {
                    title = e
                }
                listArray.push([user.name.fullName, user.name.givenName, user.name.familyName, user.primaryEmail, department, title, user.id, ]);

            }
        }
        pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
        break; // This means you only get one page
    } while (pageToken);
    try {
        var outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('allMembers');
        outputSheet.getDataRange();
    } catch (err) {
        var outputSheet = ss.insertSheet('allMembers', 2);
    }
    outputSheet.getDataRange().clear();
    outputSheet.getRange(1, 1, listArray.length, listArray[0].length).setValues(listArray);
    outputSheet.getRange(1, 6, outputSheet.getLastRow(), 4).setHorizontalAlignment("center");
    outputSheet.getRange(1, 1, outputSheet.getLastRow(), 1).setHorizontalAlignment("center");
    var width = [150, 150, 180, 250, 250, 200];
    formatSheet(outputSheet, width);
}
```

**UPDATE**

To only list the users in a certain department you would just need to add a `if` around the `push`

```
 if(department == '--NAME OF DEPARTMENT--'){
      listArray.push([user.name.fullName, user.name.givenName, user.name.familyName, user.primaryEmail, department, title, user.id,]);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks James, I will take a look at this. I was using the Directory API documentation (which is working for the other values I am trying to look up).

Comment: Sorry, the Users | Directory API documentation.

Comment: Ya, the documentation is quite scattered. If it doesn't work post back and let us know, I'll set up the fields and test them on my domain.

Comment: Doesn't look like we are using those fields. Just comes back as undefined. We use GADs to sync from AD into G Suite, which is where it is pulling the Department information from.

Comment: Even I am facing same problem -- any solutions 

I am using "user.organizations[0].department o and user.organizations[0].title"

Comment: @Moonie Please see my updated answer, this should do the trick.

Comment: @JamesD I never even thought of that! Fantastic. You're a star!

Comment: @JamesD Anyway you are aware of to restrict it pulling people that match a certain criteria? Like just a certain department?

Answer (score 0):

Using admin SDK and query you can [search user](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) on the basis of attributes like OrgName, ManagerId, Ref Link[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users).
Pass query in your request

```
     var queryStr="orgDepartment=HR"
     var page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
                    domain : 'example.com',
                    orderBy : 'givenName',
                    pageToken : pageToken,
                    query:queryStr
                });
```